# How to apply css to each element other than the last, from a specific group

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have spans with className `SearchHighlightGroup{x}` where x is a positive integer that can have any value.
For a given `x`, if we look at the spans with className `SearchHighlightGroup{x}` as a group, I want to apply a style to each one of them, except for the last one. I want that for each x possible.
For example, if I have:

```
<span class="SearchHighlightGroup1">sp11</span>
<span class="SearchHighlightGroup1">sp12</span>
<span class="SearchHighlightGroup2">sp21</span>
<span class="SearchHighlightGroup2">sp22</span>
<span class="SearchHighlightGroup3">sp31</span>
```

I want to apply my style to sp11, sp21 - *and other spans that could be here.*
Can I achieve that using pure css? scss if not?

Comment: Not possible I guess. If x represents a group, then group those elements using DIVs or any semantic element of your choice.

Comment: PS: `:has` could be used but be ready for complains from iOS users who can't update their browsers.

Comment: If javascript is an option, it would be rather easy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible using the new `nth-child(An + B of S)` but you have to define each case alone. Sass can help you generate all the selectors

```css
span:nth-last-child(n + 2 of [class*=SearchHighlightGroup1]) {
  color: red;
}
span:nth-last-child(n + 2 of [class*=SearchHighlightGroup2]) {
  color: blue;
}
span:nth-last-child(n + 2 of [class*=SearchHighlightGroup3]) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<span>ignore</span>
<span class="SearchHighlightGroup1">sp11</span>
<span class="SearchHighlightGroup1">sp12</span>
<span class="SearchHighlightGroup2">sp21</span>
<span class="SearchHighlightGroup2">sp22</span>
<span>ignore</span>
<span>ignore</span>
<span class="SearchHighlightGroup3">sp31</span>
<span>ignore</span>
```

Here a Sass code to generate as many selectors as you want:

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  span:nth-last-child(n + 2 of [class*=SearchHighlightGroup#{$i}]) {color: red;}
}
```

Comment: How good is the browser support though?

Comment: @SalmanA as far as I know, it's supported in all the browsers

Comment: The `of` part... how good is the support?

Comment: Pretty bad support https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_nth-last-child_of_syntax. BTW, the chart does not tell you what browser you're client/boss is using.

Comment: @SalmanA https://caniuse.com/css-nth-child-of

Comment: So I guess MDN is using outdated data. Anyway, support only limited to latest build of browsers... not practical as-of now, may be in one year.